# How to restore a Debian system with a backup of "/"?

Tags: backup, backup-restoration

How can I restore my Debian system with a tar-backup of the whole "/"-folder (all files und folders)?

Must I create an ISO or what?

Comment: Why so many dislikes? Are beginners here not welcome?

Comment: You need to add more details, and do a little more research first, such as what specific problem you need to address restoring the backup, etc.  If you're simply looking for instructions on how to restore a backup, this is likely the wrong place to do it.

Comment: That's why I ask here. I haven't find something useful by searching on Google.

Comment: `Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment.`  So no, beginners that simply ask others how to do things without trying them are not welcome here.

Comment: "Not welcome here" is not the correct vernacular, but that's the policy basically.  You need to describe your technical problem in some detail.  Also, I'm not a Debian guru by any stretch of the imagination, but I don't think that this is a supported or recommended method of restoring a Debian system.

Comment: Restore it under what conditions?  A total drive failure, the loss of some files?  The corruption of something?  Details matter!

Comment: I googled `backup restore tar debian` and found lots of promising links. Be prepared to invest some time, or else hire someone. First & most important: If your tar archive is now the only copy of un-replaceable data, make a backup of it right away. If you have to buy another hard drive to do this, buy one. And yes, you'll probably need some kind of live CD. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

If someone gave me a tar archive of a completely failed system and asked me to restore it I would probably do things about like this.

- Get working hardware
- Boot working hardware off [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/)
- Extract the `/etc/fstab` from the tar to get an idea of the correct filesystem setup
- Partition, format, etc the drives and mount them somewhere, maybe `/target`
- Extract the tar archive to my mountpoint (ie `/target`)
- Re-setup whatever bootloader was being previously used.  Details would depend on bootloader being used (eg grub, grub2, lilo, ...).
- Possibly correct the `/etc/fstab`, and other related files that may be referencing filesystems by UUID.  It all depends on if LVM, RAID, FDE, or something else was in use.

This is far from the only way though.  I could probably come up with a dozen different ways that may be better or worse depending on the specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to boot into a recovery disk, or Debian live CD (https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/#stable), etc. and then restore, but are you certain something less drastic cant be done?

Not sure what you are fixing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you are already booted into the system and need to untar the root filesystem. First create a directory that isn't included in the original filesystem. Move the tarball to that directory and just extract it.

If your filesystem is toast, then you'll need to boot into a live CD, mount the hard drive (/dev/sdb or whatever it might be), and then extract the tarball to that mounted location.

If any of the system changed, like grub or drivers, then things get a little bit more complicated. Additional information will help us tremendously in helping you out.